# Flag immediately accepted?

Tags: support, flagging

I just flagged a comment as being "rude or disrespectful," and as soon as I pressed "OK" to flag it, the comment disappeared. When I checked my flags, I saw that it had been marked as "helpful," but this was immediately after I had flagged it. Is there some mechanic that would make it so if enough people flag a comment, they will all be marked as "helpful" immediately? Or is there something else I'm missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there some mechanic that would make it so if enough people flag a comment, they will all be marked as "helpful" immediately?

Yes, and 'enough people' may be **one**, depending on the content of the comment. See this Meta Stack Exchange question for more details: [What is the SE version of Seven Dirty Words?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238835/295232)

If the system doesn't deem the comment worthy of deletion after one flag, it'll be gone (most of the times) after **three** flags (the exception is when the comment got a few upvotes already).